# Visual Studio - Manage Bower Packages - ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://...", exit code of #128

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, bower

**Background**

I created empty ASP .NET MVC project, opened *Manage Bower Packages* window and tried to install foo package.
I receive following error:

```
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Web\External\Bower.cmd" install foo#v4.0.0 --force-latest --save
bower foo#v4.0.0       not-cached https://github.com/bar/foo.git#v4.0.0
bower foo#v4.0.0          resolve https://github.com/bar/foo.git#v4.0.0
bower foo#v4.0.0          ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/bar/foo.git", exit code of #128
```

---

**Question**
How do I fix the above error?

---

**Note**
This question strictly relates to Visual Studio. In this case running following command **does not fix** the problem.

`git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

Comment: Did you find a VS / TFS / MS solution?